# Amazon Workspace: upload / download files from / to local computer

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I am using an Amazon Linux Workspace and cannot find if there is a direct way to upload / download files from / to my local computer. Is it possible? For example, using an ftp server, or maybe with ssh?

Thanks in advance.